# Pull information from table to modal to edit

Tags: php, javascript

Ok I have a table that is set up to display information pulled from a database.

At the end of this table I have an update button. I am using bootstrap and when you click this button you open up a modal with a form, I am wanting the values from the certain row to be passed into the forms so the user can edit the information.

The table is generated with this:

```
<?php
                $con=mysqli_connect("50.63.106.181","TheGreenPandaWeb","MacBook1!","TheGreenPandaWeb");
                // Check connection
                if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                  {
                  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                  }

                $query = "SELECT * FROM affiliate_tasks WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'";

                if( isset($_POST['sort-selection']) && $_POST['sort-selection'] != 'all' ) 
                {
                    $query .= " AND status = '". $_POST['sort-selection']."';" ;
                }

                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                echo "<table class='table table-message table-hover'>
                <tr class='heading'>
                <td class='cell-title'>Tasks</td> 
                <td class='cell-status hidden-phone hidden-tablet'>Status</td> 
                <td class='cell-time align-right'>Due Date</td>
                <td class='check-box' width='10px'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class='check-box' width='10px'>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>";

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                  {
                  echo "<tr class='task " . ($row['resolved'] == 1 ? 'resolved' : '') . "' id='task-$row[task_id]'>";
                  echo "<td class='cell-ttle'>" . $row['task_name'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td class='cell-status hidden-phone hidden-tablet " . ($row['status'] == Done ? 'text-success' : '') ." " . ($row['status'] == Overdue ? 'text-warning' : '') ."'>"  . $row['status'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td class='cell-time align-right'>" . $row['due_date'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td class='check-box' width='10px'>" . "<a class='icon-arrow-up' href='#updateTaskModal' role='button' data-toggle='modal'></a>" . "</td>";
                  echo "<td class='check-box' width='10px'>" . "<a class='icon-remove' href='#deleteTaskModal' role='button' data-toggle='modal'></a>" . "</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                  }
                echo "</table>";

                mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
```

and the form looks like so:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="new_task" action="scripts/form_scripts/new_task.php" method="post"> 
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="hide" value="<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION[username]; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="task_name">Task Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="task_name" id="task_name" placeholder="Something with description.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="status">Task Status</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select id="status" name="status">
                        <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                        <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                        <option value="Done">Done</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="due_date">Due Date</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="date" name="due_date" id="due_date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am figuring you will need javascript but i'm not sure where to start.

Comment: did you write jQuery/Javascript code  ??

Comment: You can do this two ways, you can pull the data from the DOM, or you can just get the id and then do an ajax call, to get the data from server, which way do you want?

Comment: KyleK -- Getting information from the DOM sounds easier. But the ajax call sounds more solid. Which one would you prefer?

Comment: I would do the DOM, since it doesnt require another call, to the server....but both ways are equally good

Comment: Ok. then the DOM it is. How could I get started?

Comment: Answer below....incase you haven't seen it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it....
Give the a tag a class of "update", and populate some data attributes in the tag, as below.

```
echo "<a class='icon-arrow-up update' href='#updateTaskModal' data-status='".$row['status']."'  data-name='".$row['task_name']."' data-date='".$row['due_date']."' role='button' data-toggle='modal'></a>";
```

Then your Jquery would go as follows..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('a.update').click(function(){
   var name = $(this).data('name');
   var date = $(this).data('date');
   var status = $(this).data('status');    

   $('#task_name').val(name);
   $('#status').val(status);
   $('#due_date').val(date);
    });

 });
```

Ideally you will integrate this code into the modal callback.....not too familiar with twitter bootstrap off the top of my head though, so Ill let you figure that part out

PS completely untested code, just providing you an idea here....Im sure you can figure it out from here. :)

Comment: I would like you to know your answer worked right off the press!

Comment: Awesome :)  I love it when that happens ;)  If only it worked like that when Im coding my own stuff....lol

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use greybox or fancybox where you can pass your value on url. And then you will be able to retrieve those value inside the called page.